# iPhoneアプリ作成に必要なハードウェア・ソフトウェア

Tags: iphone

iPhoneアプリを作成したいと思っているんですがiMacとiPhoneとobjectiveCとXCODEの他に揃えるものはありますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[iPhone] アプリを作る：準備編（１）](https://akira-watson.com/iphone/begin-1.html)
この辺が参考になりそうです（（５）まであります）。

以下、リンク先から転載

> アプリ開発の概要
>
> 1.開発ツール、Xcodeをインストール
>   　→ Mac PC が必要
>   2.Xcode を使ってコーディング
>   　→ Swift あるいは Objective-C での記述
>   3.シミュレーターで確認
>   4.iPhone 実機でアプリを確認する
>   　→ ソフトの勉強だけならここまでで終わりとすることもあり
>   5.アップルに開発者登録をする
>   　→ アプリを公開したい場合は、開発者登録をする
>   　→ 年間参加費 ¥11,800 (税別)（US$99ですが為替で変わります）
>   6.アップルにアプリの申請を行い、承認されると公開できます

Answer (score 1):

補足になりますが、iMacのかわりにMac MiniやMac Book Pro/Airでも(スペック的に)使えます。

Comment: ディスプレイサイズ的にお勧めできません。

Answer (score 1):

The answer from ita_3y should address this problem well. I just want to add that in the new versions of Xcode, such as 6 or 7, you can get the app that you created exported to your iPhone, rather than run it in the simulator. You can do this to start with instead of paying the fee.

（参考訳）
ita_3y さんの回答に加え、Xcodeの新しいバージョン（6や7）もあるとよいです。そうすればお金を払って開発者登録することなく、実機でアプリを動かすことができます。

---

以下、編集者による補足です。

以前はアプリを実機で動かすためには開発者登録が必要だったのですが、Xcode7 から一般の Apple ID でも実機で動かせるようになりました。

- http://www.softantenna.com/wp/ios/xcode-7-with-apple-id/

また、開発者登録していない場合、In-App Purchase など一部の機能が利用できないようです。

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SupportedCapabilities/SupportedCapabilities.html
- https://developer.apple.com/programs/whats-included/jp/